# How to force FactoryGirl to create parent before creating factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have an Event model that, when saved, updates some attributes on the parent User.

```
class User
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :update_user_attributes

  validates :user, presence: true

  def update_user_attributes
    self.user.update_attributes(hash_of_params)
  end
end
```

This works fine most of the time — a User must exist and be logged in before they can interact with an Event.

But my test suite is causing problems, specifically the event factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    user
  end
end
```

It seems that, due to the order FactoryGirl builds the Event, the User is not available at the time the Event is created, causing `update_user_attributes` to fail.

This means that

```
create(:event)
# ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
# Failed to save the record
```

but

```
build(:event).save
```

passes without errors

There are a number of ways I could prevent the error being raised, e.g., check that `user.persisted?` in the `update_user_attributes` method, or run the callaback `after_save`. But my question specifically relates to FactoryGirl.

Given the above factoy, is there a way to force the associated User to be created before creating the Event?

Answer (score 9):

You can write callbacks in FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    user

    before(:create) do |event|
      create(:user, event_id: event.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is [docs link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/2.3.2/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks)

Also there is an [article on thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl) about FG callbacks

Comment: thanks @martin, this works when an event has many users. but I can't figure out how to create a parent and then user the parent's id in the event factory. it would need to be something like` before(:create) do self.user_id = create(:user).id end`. But I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: @AndyHarvey, `before(:create) do |event| event.user = create(:user) end` I suppose